# where can i add my properties file name in struts2

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

In my application each action class has the respective properties file the thing is i know only how to get the values from the properties file but i don't know where to add the properties file name in my application and i want to add new properties file for  my application without action class for only jsp.

Please help me where to call the properties file name struts.xml.

Comment: Is a resource bundle? Or is a personal properties file for you application? Can you tell us where is exactly your problem?

Comment: i want add properties file that has no action class ,i want to add that properties file in my jsp. where to call the properties file name in struts2 please help

Comment: @srujan:can you be more clear like what kind of property files? are they resource bundles or any other property file as there can be many ways to access them based on what you are trying to do

Comment: where to call resource bundle  in struts2

Comment: In google you have examples. Look at this: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-resource-bundle-example/

Answer (score -2):

/web/WEB-INF/classes is the usual place.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: why? It is the ANSWER . The path to where to put what the user asks. So why shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: Because you are asking to be more clear about what he is asking lol

Comment: k i have added my properties file in /web/WEB-INF/classes but where to call that property file name for example in struts1 <message: resource key="app.properties"> in struts2 where to call that properties file

Comment: @Pigueiras: You can flag it, you know. Anyway I removed that bit so now it looks more like an answer.

Comment: k i have added my properties file in /web/WEB-INF/classes but where to call that property file name for example in struts1 <message: resource key="app.properties"> in struts2 where to call that properties file

Comment: I would caveat that only the `WEB-INF/classes` part is really relevant; project structure varies, e.g., this wouldn't be the correct place in a Maven project.